# Translate the source address of all packets leaving a particular interface with nftables

Tags: nftables

I am running Ubuntu Server 18-04 VM on Zorin host.

I am wanting to translate the source address of all packets leaving via enp0s3 to 192.168.1.120 with nftables. This is what I have done:

```
apt install nftables

modprobe nft_nat

modprobe nft_chain_nat_ipv4

nft add table nat

nft add chain nat post { type nat hook postrouting priority 0 \; }

nft add chain nat pre { type nat hook prerouting priority 0 \; }

nft add rule nat postrouting oif enp0s3 snat to 192.168.2.120
```

I get:

```
Error: Could not process rule: No such file or directory
```

According to this post [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/nftables)

> "Note: You may have to create /etc/modules-load.d/nftables.conf with
>   all of the nftables related modules you require as entries for the
>   systemd service to work correctly. You can get a list of modules using
>   this command: $ lsmod | grep '^nf' Otherwise, you could end up with
>   the dreaded Error: Could not process rule: No such file or directory
>   error."

The output of $ lsmod | grep '^nf' is:

```
nft_chain_nat_ipv4     16384  2    
nf_conntrack_ipv4      16384  1    
nf_defrag_ipv4         16384  1 nf_conntrack_ipv4    
nf_nat_ipv4            16384  1 nft_chain_nat_ipv4    
nft_nat                16384  0    
nf_nat                 32768  2 nft_nat,nf_nat_ipv4    
nf_conntrack          131072  4    
nft_nat,nf_conntrack_ipv4,nf_nat_ipv4,nf_nat    
nf_tables_inet         16384  4    
nf_tables_ipv6         16384  1 nf_tables_inet    
nf_tables_ipv4         16384  2 nf_tables_inet    
nf_tables              90112  5     
nft_nat,nft_chain_nat_ipv4,nf_tables_ipv6,nf_tables_ipv4,nf_tables_i$    
nfnetlink              16384  1 nf_tables
```

I have cut and pasted this into the `/etc/modules-load.d/nftables.conf` file without success.

Does anyone know how I can resolve this error?

EDIT:

I changed the order I added the chains, I added the "pre" chain first and the "post" chain second. Now I am getting a different error:

```
nft add rule nat postrouting oif eno1 snat to 192.168.2.120
<cmdline>:1:40-41: Error: syntax error, unexpected to
add rule nat postrouting oif eno1 snat to 192.168.2.120
                                       ^^
```

This error seems odd to me as I got this syntax for the nftables manpage:

Using NAT statements

## create a suitable table/chain setup for all further examples

add table nat
add chain nat prerouting { type nat hook prerouting priority 0; }
add chain nat postrouting { type nat hook postrouting priority 100; }

## translate source addresses of all packets leaving via eth0 to address 1.2.3.4

**add rule nat postrouting oif eth0 snat to 1.2.3.4**

Answer (score 0):

The rule should be 
  **nft add rule nat post "subnet address of enp0s3" snat to 192.168.2.120**

The example of **subnet address of enp0s3** may be like **10.4.0.1/16**

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out.

"postrouting" is not the hook but the name of the chain. As my chain was named "post" the correct syntax is:

```
nft add rule nat post oif enp0s3 snat to 192.168.2.120
```